# Obter valores de método para ter resultado na calculadora ANDROID

Tags: java, android, mobile

Amigos, agora a duvida é a seguinte, preciso que a operação "+", esteja presente para realizar a soma, porem sempre sai 1+2 e nunca os dois fazem a soma. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser ?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class Inicio extends Activity {
TextView tela;
Button btnreset, btnraiz, btnporcentagem, btndesfazer,
        btnsubtracao, btnum1, btnum2, btnum3,
btnsoma, btnum4, btnum5, btnum6,
        btnmultiplicacao, btnum7, btnum8, btnum9,
        btndivisao, btnum0, btnponto, btnresutado;

String resultado;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);

    tela = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tela);
    btnreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    btnraiz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.raiz);
    btnporcentagem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.porcentagem);
    btndesfazer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.desfazer);
    btnsubtracao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.subtracao);
    btnum1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.um);
    btnum2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dois);
    btnum3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tres);
    btnsoma = (Button) findViewById(R.id.soma);
    btnum4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quatro);
    btnum5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cinco);
    btnum6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seis);
    btnmultiplicacao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multiplicacao);
    btnum7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sete);
    btnum8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.oito);
    btnum9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nove);
    btndivisao = (Button) findViewById(R.id.divisao);
    btnum0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.zero);
    btnponto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ponto);
    btnresutado = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resultado);



}
 public void digito(View v) {

   switch (v.getId()) {

       case R.id.um:

           resultado+=Integer.parseInt(btnum1.getText().toString());
            tela.append(btnum1.getText());


            break;

       case R.id.dois:

           resultado+=Integer.parseInt(btnum2.getText().toString());
           tela.append(btnum2.getText());


            break;


       case R.id.soma:


           resultado+=String.valueOf(btnsoma.getText().toString());
           tela.append(btnsoma.getText());

            break;

       case R.id.resultado:

           tela.append(resultado);

           break;

   }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode deixar muito mais enxuto o seu código, vamos lá.

os métodos `num1`,`num2`...`num9`,`subtrai`, etc podem virar um só da seguinte forma.
No seu xml você deve estar chamando os métodos através do atributo `android:onclick=numX`, certo? faça todos os botões chamarem apenas um método,
`android:onclick=digito` e no java vai criar um único método para todos os botões numéricos e operadores.

```
private void digito(View v){
   //a view que está sendo passada por 
   //parametro nada mais é que o proprio botão que foi pressionado.
   //então devemos dizer que essa view é um botão da seguinte maneira
   Button btDigito = (Button)v;
   //recuperamos o valor do botão
   String valor = btDigito.getText().toString();
   //adiciona o valor para um string que vai acumulando a formula
   result += valor;
}
```

**Opção1**

```
private void calcular(){
     Binding binding   = new Binding();  
     GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);  
     //exibe na tela, não sei como você vai mostrar na tela o resultado
     // portanto defini esse método exibirResultado;
     exibirResultado(shell.evaluate(resultado));
}
```

**Opção 2**

```
private void calcular(){
    ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    exibirResultado(engine.eval(resultado));
}
```

Confesso que não testei o método calcular apenas retirei de pesquisas que fiz no google, é preciso testar, acredito que há varias formas de resolver o seu problema, apenas passei a resposta mais simples que acredito que seja, mas se não der certo avise que posso reformular o método de outras maneiras.

Comment: Deu uma pequena luz a sua ideia, agora eu botei no case os botões, pegando pelo ID da Viewer . O problema agora é na conversão dos dados, pois o resultado ta saindo null1+2. Editei o conteúdo a cima.

Comment: A variavel `resultado` ta saindo isso pq voce nao inicio ele, no onCreate você inicia ele da seguinte forma,  `resultado="";`

Comment: A sim, obrigado pela ajuda. Só falta mesmo a parte do resultado sair a soma dos valores corretamente.

Comment: criei uma segunda opção do método calcular, tente ela, essa deve funcionar. FONTE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form#3423360